# Using JSHint (Vim) with .html Files

Tags: javascript, html, vim, jshint

I just installed JSHint in Vim and so far it works as expected. The only thing I don't seem to get working is checking syntax in .html files (in .js it works flawlessly). I.e., when I have a `<script>`-Section in a .html File, it would like to get that checked as well upon saving the buffer or calling `:JSHint`.

What to do?

Comment: Well… did you check if `jshint` even work on JS embedded in HTML?

Comment: What did you mean by that? That's what I am saying.. but yeah, I just checked       jshint test.html in the shell, and it doesn't show any output either.

Comment: The JSHint Vim plugin and the `jshint` CLI program are different things: the Vim plugin is a frontend for the CLI program. Your whole question is revolving around the Vim plugin and I asked you if the backend does what you want as its an obvious prerequisite for the frontend to offer that feature. It looks like it doesn't so you'd better get into the habit of writing your JS in `.js` files. FYI, JSLint, its predecessor, does support JS in HTML.

Comment: Alright, question (unofficially) answered - thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's quite so impossible.  It should be possible to chain a series of commands that extract part of a file, save it to a tempfile, run jshint on that tempfile, pull the results back in and display them back...  some starting points: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Filtering-text-through-external-commands-td4266604.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jshint added support for extracting js from inside html files [about a month ago](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/1352).  It's the `--extract` option at the command line ([docs here](http://jshint.com/docs/cli/))

I'm not sure which jshint plugin you're using, but if you can tweak the command-line params it passes to jshint, then you just need to add

```
--extract=always
```

and then somehow set jshint to also do linting for html files.

I'm [trying](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/pull/925) to get this to work in syntastic...